# Multi level (hierarchical) visualisation using D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have geographical information represented as tuples like `[lon, lat, vx, vy, t, h]` standing for speed of wind, temperature and humidity.
I would like to explore this data and have in mind to use D3 for this.
Since I have a huge number of points (abt 100 millions) my idea was to embed the data in a D3 quadtree and have a slider that will let me explore the data by level.
For doing this it seems that I need to change the `d3-quadtree.v1.js` since I need to create/attach information for each intermediate node of the quadtree (some kind of averaged vx, vy, t, h for child nodes). This is possible using `quadtree.visitAfter` function but the storage does not seem possible in the node themselves. 
Since I am newbie in using D3 I was looking at getting some feedback from people that might have face the same problem.
Obviously I can share my code if some people are willing to review this.

Comment: woaaahhh, you won't be able to load 100 million points client-side (rough calc: 100M * 6vars * 8bytes  var = 4.8GB) let alone process them in a web browser. Any aggregating (which is basically what a quad-tree does) on that scale would have to be done server-side. I've managed to get data sets of a million or so working but that involved hacking d3 code itself to make it use less memory per object. If anyone knows any different an example would be great!

Comment: thanks @mgraham for the comment. Since my recording device sampling rate is quite high (and his speed is quite slow) I can probably discard a fair amount of point to come close to some millions of points. Who you describe the kind of hacks that you had to perform to realize something similar? For the time being the hack I am doing are rather increasing the memory - for enabling intermediate storage of aggregated information rather than decreasing footprint :-(

Comment: In my case I was using the d3 hierarchy algorithms. I changed it so leaf nodes didn't instantiate variables like children arrays they didn't need (since most of the nodes in my tree were leaves) to save space - and I only drew a certain amount at a time for speed and memory. I squashed stuff into shared variables i.e. top 32 bits of an integer was one variable, bottom 32 bits another. Where there were arrays I used the typed 16/32 bit versions etc - and still it was just enough. I did have a map but I used leaflet.js and it had a good clustering plug-in.

Comment: If someone is interested  I have made an experiment available on my github [repo](https://rawgit.com/galleon/d3xp3rim3nts/master/index.html). I tried 1M elements and it's indeed slow. I might need to compress the info as suggested to go a bit higher.  All comments on the code are welcomed :-)